# Sentence is not inserted into online database not from all devices

Tags: android, database

When I insert a sentence from my android phone, the data is not inserted to my database. But when I use my friend's mobile, it works successfully.

It actually does not work when I use space between two words. But, when I use a single word, it works.

I use VARCHAR in my database.

**Here is my java code:**

```
EditText cname, location, num, email, pass;
Button submit;

private static final String REGISTER_URL = "https://alex456.000webhostapp.com/Register.php";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    cname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText8);
    location = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText10);
    email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText11);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.CUPCAKE)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerUser();
        }
    });

}

private void registerUser(){
    String CNAME, LOCATION, NUM, PASS ,EMAIL;
    CNAME = cname.getText().toString().trim();
    LOCATION = location.getText().toString().trim();
    NUM = num.getText().toString().trim();
    EMAIL = email.getText().toString().trim();
    PASS = pass.getText().toString().trim();

    register(CNAME, LOCATION, NUM, EMAIL, PASS);
}

private void register(String CNAME,String LOCATION,String NUM,String EMAIL, String PASS ) {
    String urlSuffix = "?cnamePHP=" + CNAME + "&locationPHP=" + LOCATION + "&numPHP=" + NUM + "&emailPHP=" + EMAIL + "&passPHP=" + PASS;

    class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog loading;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(RegisterActivity.this, "Please Wait", null, true, true);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String s = params[0];
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(REGISTER_URL + s);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String result;
                result = bufferedReader.readLine();
                return result;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Intent i;
            i = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    RegisterUser ur = new RegisterUser();
    ur.execute(urlSuffix);
}
```

}